# How to check Network availability or checking network and turn on mobile network?

Tags: java, android

As a beginner, I am trying to develop an `Android` application, which is fetching data from server database.

Here, if **`Wi-Fi`** is not available at place, **I need to turn on** a **`3G`**- or a **`2G`**-data, which is provided on the Android device automatically or by a dialog box to turn on the mobile network.

Answer (score 1):

How to check for WIFI internet connection:

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
    // Do whatever
}
```

Add Permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

How to Check for for mobile internet connections (3G/LTE):

```
boolean is3g = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            .isConnectedOrConnecting();

// Checks if Mobile network is available ...

if(!is3g){

// IF MOBILE CONNECTION NOT AVAILBLE, OPEN SYSTEM SETTINGS FOR MOBILE NETWORKS

   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
   startActivity(intent);

}
```

Hope this helps, please mark it as accepted answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the network is available or not, by this class

```
 public class ConnectionDetector {

private Context _context;
public ConnectionDetector(Context context){
    this._context = context;
}

/**
 * Checking for all possible Internet providers
 * **/
public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null)
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null)
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }

      }
      return false;
}
```

}

check for internet

```
  ConnectionDetector conn = new ConnectionDetector(youractivity.this);
    if(conn.isConnectingToInternet()){
        // call network operations
    }else{
        // Toast
    }
```

hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

use this code to check the availability of network:-

```
public class CheckConnection {
```

private Context _context;

```
public CheckConnection(Context context){
    this._context = context;
}

public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null) 
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null) 
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) 
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }

      }
      return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(
                        new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                // Check for n/w connection
                                if (!NetworkService
                                        .isNetWorkAvailable(CurrentActivity.this)) {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                            CurrentActivity.this);
                                    // set title
                                    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Warning");
                                    alertDialogBuilder
                                            .setMessage("Check your network connection and try again.");
                                    // set dialog message
                                    alertDialogBuilder
                                            .setCancelable(false)
                                            .setNegativeButton(
                                                    "Ok",
                                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                        public void onClick(
                                                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                int id) {
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                    // create alert dialog
                                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                                    // show it
                                    alertDialog.show();
                                } else {
                              // Do your action if network exists
                                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(i);
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

NetworkService.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public final class NetworkService {

    private NetworkService() {}

    public static boolean isNetWorkAvailable(final Context contextActivity) {
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) contextActivity.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Add these permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: findViewById ... really?

Comment: @Ayub Yes, findViewById what is your doubt?

Comment: i assumed UI elements were irrelevant in this question, but then again, i could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

to check network is available or not use following block of code

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context mContext) {
    // TODO Check network connection
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

and next do following check condition for if WIFI not available :-

```
private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) {
final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
```

}
you also required this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Checking for all possible internet providers
public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){

    ConnectivityManager connectivity = 
                         (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(
                          Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      if (connectivity != null)
      {
          NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
          if (info != null)
              for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                  if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                  {
                      return true;
                  }

      }
      return false;
}
```

Also specify these permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
```